# A string without reversing words. Words are separated by dots

Tags: go

Like this-Using go lang in go lang using (for loop and range fun)

Given a String S, reverse the string without reversing its individual words. Words are separated by dots.

Input : i.like.this.program.very.much
Output: much.very.program.this.like.i

```
package main 
    import (
       "fmt"
       "strings"
    ) 
    func main() {
       str := " i.like.this.program.very.much"
       words := strings.Split(str, " ")
       len := len(words)
       for i := 0; i<len/2; i++ {
          tmp := words[len-i-1]
          words[len-i-1] = words[i]
          words[i] = tmp
       }
       str = strings.Join(words," ")
       fmt.Println(str)
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

https://goplay.tools/snippet/EEFOAYGfQ6z

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "i.like.this.program.very.much"
    r := reverseWords(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(r)
}

func reverseWords(s string) string {
    words := strings.Split(s, ".")
    reversedWords := reverse(words)
    r := strings.Join(reversedWords, ".")
    return r
}

func reverse(arr []string) []string {
    for i, j := 0, len(arr)-1; i < j; {
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
        i++
        j--
    }
    return arr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "i.like.this.program.very.much"
    res1 := strings.Split(str, ".")
    revString := ""
    for i := len(res1) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        revString += res1[i]
        if i != 0 {
            revString += "."
        }
    }
    fmt.Print(revString)
}
```